# KeyError: 'getpwuid(): uid not found: 381206'

Tags: python

I'm running the following code to get owner of all files:

```
try:
    st=os.stat(file_path)
    uid=st.st_uid
    userinfo=pwd.getpwuid(st.st_uid)
    owner=pwd.getpwuid(st.st_uid).pw_name
    file_info.append((size,file_path,owner))
except OSError as e:
    pass
```

However, in the middle of the processing, it throws up the following error:

> KeyError: 'getpwuid(): uid not found: 381206'

Do anyone know about this error? Are there any known issues with `pwd` in `Python 2.6` ?

Please notice that this is just the part of the code I considered relevant, I can provide more if required.

Comment: The file could perhaps be owned by a [deleted user](https://serverfault.com/questions/397982/what-happens-to-a-users-files-when-i-delete-the-user-in-linux)

Comment: so how do i skip such files.. i have added the except but doesnt seem to work in this case.

Comment: You could catch `KeyError`.

Comment: The UID seems a bit high to me. You might want to run a filesystem check.

Comment: @RolandSmith- there are huge no. of files in the disk. so i guess that no should be expected.

Comment: just to update . i caught the keyerror and that fixed it. thank you

Answer (score 0):

The error happens in my python ver `3.5` as well in Linux.
In my case, once a person leaves the company, his/her UID is replaced with a number and `pwd.getpwuid(st.st_uid)` fails with the error.

I replaced it with `sh.stat('-c', '%U', <path>).stdout.decode('utf-8').strip()`, which returns `UNKNOWN`.